# Can I apply an entire style sheet to just one div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a **dynamic bootstrap calendar** in a website I am building. I have a style sheet for my site, but the calendar has its own styles, and no matter what I do something from one sheet ruins the other elements (my header is ruined by the calendar stylesheet, and the calendar becomes wonky and asymmetrical because of my stylesheet.)

I tried putting a class in a class (below) and giving that class to a div and putting the calendar code inside it but it did not work.

```css
.calendar_content{
sub {
  bottom: -.25em; }

sup {
  top: -.5em; }

a {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent; }
  a:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
    text-decoration: underline; }

a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none; }
  a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):hover, a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none; }
  a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus {
    outline: 0; }

pre,
code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 1em; }

pre {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: auto; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="calendar_content"> Calendar code </div>
```

I also tried using id (below) but it didn't work either.

```
CSS: #calendar_content{the entire stylesheet content}
HTML: <div id="calendar_content"> Calendar code </div>
```

Additional info: there are js files involved but I don't believe it's affecting the view of the site.

Comment: _"I tried putting a class in a class"_ - that is not syntax native CSS currently supports; you'd need to use a preprocessor language like LESS or SASS for that to work.

Comment: Can you add to the question an example of the rules that are in "the entire stylesheet content"? Also are all elements that you are trying to style inside the wrapper div? If no this will be harder

Comment: @Kaddath done. And no, some classes define the padding/margin, other lists, etc.

Comment: @CBroe [CSS nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting) is now a standard. [Not widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting), granted, but it's a standard.

Comment: Beyond just setting some "resets" using element names in styles if fraught with challenges i.e. things like `a {` , `div {` , and `pre,
code,
kbd,
samp {` and you appear to have a lot of those. and why are you using an anchor tag that has no href? `a:not([href])`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I'm using a calendar template from bootstrap; this css is the one uploaded with the template. either way there's a lot of head-scratching to do with this; i'll se what i can do. thanks anywas

Comment: OK, let's update your question with a working example with bootstrap and tag with that!

Comment: I created a snippet but have no idea WHICH calendar you are using to best assist you here.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using react/nextjs you just import the css file in the calendar component as module

```
import cssFileName.module.css
```

if you are using native html/css , you will need to use sass/scss/less to be able to use syntax like class nesting ex:

```
.class1{
   .class2{
      color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why saying that tools the OP is most probably not using are needed to solve the problem, while an obvious solution exists: refactor the styles to depend on the wrapper class, eg `.class1.class2 { ... }` or `.class1 .class2 { ... }`?

Comment: could you expand on the first point please? So I can explore/research it further. I am using native html/css, yes, but it depends on a sass compiler in the browser which does not match with the project needs.

Comment: Just to note that class nesting is there on major browsers, but with restrictions. https://caniuse.com/?search=nested%20

Answer (score 0):

While you can by prefixing each CSS rule to support situations that do not support the nested CSS or avoid SCSS or SASS etc. this can get ugly.

```css
.calendar_content sub {
  bottom: -.25em;
}

.calendar_content sup {
  top: -.5em;
}

.calendar_content a {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.calendar_content a:hover {
  color: #0056b3;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.calendar_content a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.calendar_content a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):hover,
.calendar_content a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.calendar_content a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.calendar_content pre,
.calendar_content code,
.calendar_content kbd,
.calendar_content samp {
  font-family: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.calendar_content pre {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="calendar_content"> Calendar code </div>
```

Comment: yep, that's what i feared. i'll try reading into nested css but if all fails looks like i'll have to do this unfortunately. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is nesting in CSS, but You would still have to add `&` to each nested rule, like this:

```css
.calendar_content {
   color:red;
   & a{
    color: green;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar_content"> no link <a href="#">link</a></div>
```

I guess the only way to do it automatically would be to use JavaScript to rewrite rules of calendar and all the other elements.